# How to Install sybase unwired platform on mac os

Tags: sybase, sup

Can anyone tell me how to install Sybase Unwired Platform on my Macbook? What is the procedure, and what are the prerequisites?

Answer (score 1):

According to Sybase Documentation, Sybase Unwired Platform requires Windows.  This means you will likely have to install and run it via Parallels or Boot Camp.

More information can be found here:
[Sybase Unwired Platform Documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.pubs.docset-SUP-2.1.0/doc/html/title.html)

Download information about Sybase SUP can be found here:
[Sybase Unwired Platorm](http://www.sybase.in/products/mobileenterprise/sybaseunwiredplatform)

Comment: Thank you ..but can you tell me from where i will download the SUP,as I am not getting any link or site for download............

Comment: If you were looking for download links as well, that would have been good to know in your original question.  I've added the link to the product homepage, which includes the "Try & Buy" tab.